# Should I use a dash instead of double vowels in a domain name?

Tags: domains

Let's say I am trying to register a domain name - dangerous to talk about before the fact, I know.

First off my purpose: I am creating a website to petition for changes to a state-controlled road inside of a city (yes, this is safe in my country.)

However, I want the website to be `[verb][cityname].org`.  Sadly, the *verb* and *city name* I am using seem to start and end with the same character (an "e" for example).

Should I use `[verb][cityname].org` or `[verb]-[cityname].org`? It looks kind of awkward having two e's appear next to each other.

What might be the benefits of one over the other?  Are there any statistics available on this matter?

Comment: Interesting question. I will let someone answer. But if I were to vote, I would vote to use the hyphen (-).

Comment: Why not capitalise it every time you use it e.g. www.UpgradeExampleTown.co.uk - I assume it is not a .com as you say it is safe to speak out in your country. :P

Comment: @user1833028: If you think using a dash is better for your users, use it.

Comment: Why not register both? A `.org` isn't very expensive. You could then 301 to the canonical domain. As for which one to promote, I guess that would depend on your demographics and what they're used to seeing.

Comment: Alternately, check out the new TLDs -- there are lots already online, and more coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably register both, for the little amount that it costs, just incase, and then domain forward (or frame forward if you like) the other to your preferred version.

Answer (score 0):

I think using hyphen between is alright. You can arrange the verb and city name the way you like but by putting a hyphen between them make your SEO easy.